# R shiny dashboard how to use animated icons?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm new to R, I saw that it's possible to animate some icons in dashboard on that webpage :

http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated

But I don't understand where I have to write the indicated CSS code.

Please, could you tell me ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: please include what you have tried so far

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try anything because I don't know where to put the CSS code described in the "Animated icons" paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `renderUI` together with `htmltools::HTML` and `uiOutput` to embed your HTML code directly in your `shiny` app:

```
require("shinydashboard")
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Demo"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(uiOutput("icon"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$icon <- renderUI(
      htmltools::HTML('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>')
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, but I didn't succeeded to get an animated icon in the sidebar, you know when you type a menuSubItem name with an icon. I tried as you wrote : in Ui : 'menuSubItem("Countries", icon = uiOutput("icon"), tabName = "countries", and what you wrote in Server, but the icon disappears. Thank you.

Comment: Your OP mentioned displaying animated icon in a shinydashboard. If this post answer your question, please accept it. Then you can ask a new question (eventually referring this one) about setting the icon in the sidebar, including your code trying to achieve it (since you now have a clue how to use the CSS).

Comment: The title of my post was referring to the dashboard package. Sorry for confusion and thank you very much.

Comment: `dashboardSidebar(menuSubItem("Countries", icon = uiOutput("icon"), tabName = "countries"))` works fine on my setup

Comment: You're right HubertL, I have closed and restarted my R-Studio and it works now (???), except that the icon is much bigger than before now, so I have to find how to reduce it.

Comment: change the fa-3x to 2x or 1x, or even write 0.5em instead

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `icon` function by adding a `fa-spin` class. It should work with all icons, but spinner icons have the best visual.

```
icon("refresh", class = "fa-spin")
# <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
icon("spinner", class = "fa-spin")
# <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
```